# case when null evaluates to false

Tags: postgresql

Today I was surprised by this `case` behaviour:

```
select case when null then true else false end;
 case 
------
 f
```

I would expect it to return `null` since a `null` casted to boolean yelds a `null` not a `false`:

```
select null::boolean is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Any comments on the rationale of this behaviour? What Am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're thinking of the `CASE` expression like it was taking the `null` as input to a function or operator, where null input generally results in null output:

```
regress=> SELECT 't'::boolean = NULL::boolean;
 bool 
------

(1 row)
```

wheras in fact it behaves like a `WHERE` clause in terms of null handling:

```
craig=> SELECT 't' WHERE NULL;
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)
```

In `WHERE` clauses - and in `CASE`, a `NULL` result from a test expression is treated as "not true and therefore false". In some ways it's regrettable that the SQL standard didn't make a `NULL` result in a `WHERE` expression an error instead of treating it as false, but that's how it is.

This is yet another painful symptom of `NULL`'s split personality, where the SQL spec can't decide if `NULL` means "unknown/undefined value" or "the absence of a value", much like the horrible mess with `NULL`s and aggregates.

Comment: So it is just because of the SQL spec? Postgresql developers just followed it in instead of doing the _"right thing"_? I suspected that was the case.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Yes, and that's pretty much the policy where the spec and the sane world conflict. In this case I think it's quite reasonable, though; `CASE` isn't a function, it's a special expression with its own rules. Functions can have special null handling anyway; witness Oracle's `decode`. PostgreSQL cannot fix this without rewriting the SQL spec to fix the confusion about nulls entirely, in the process making it totally incompatible with everything else out there.

Answer (score 61):

Use something like

```
case when p.parent_id is null then false else true end as has_parent
```

Answer (score 44):

In case you (also) need something like

```
if column is null then 'value'
```

Use:

```
COALESCE(column_name, 'replacment for null value') as column_name
```

In case you still need a case statement then use:

```
case COALESCE(column_name, 'asdf') 
when 'asdf' then true
else false
end as desired_column_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the coalesce. I had totally spaced on that function :P

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'select' to check DATA column for null:

```
select 
  ID,
  case (select 1 where DATA is null)
    when 1 then 'no data'
    else data
  end
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) states:

> If no WHEN ***condition*** is true then the value of the case expression is
>   the ***result*** in the ELSE clause. If the ELSE clause is omitted and no condition matches, the result is null.

Postgresql does not cast the output, and since you have an `else` condition, you're getting `false`. The next query returns a null value (Since there's no `else` condition)

```
select case when null then true end;
```

Comment: _If no WHEN condition is true_ When the condition evaluates to `null` you can't say it is not true. You don't know. It could be any one of true or false.

Comment: Is "null = true" true? No, it's null. This means the first branch is rejected and the else takes place. Conditional tests in SQL aren't boolean. Hence all the brain-ache caused by stray nulls.

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE` statement you wrote has two branches:

The one, `when null then true`, will never happen (because `null` is not equal to `true`)

And `else` branch, that will happen when there are no matches in regular `when` branches.

Example:

```
CASE WHEN val = 1 THEN 5
     WHEN val = 2 THEN 10
     ELSE 20 /*all other values, including null*/
END
```

Comment: Using your example when `val` is null you can't say if there is or there isn't a match since `null = 1` results null not false nor true.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: `CASE` enters the first branch where the condition evaluates to `TRUE`. If no branch is `TRUE`, `ELSE` wins, which defaults to `NULL` if missing. That's the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select case when null is null then null else 1 end
```

returns null

```
select case null when then null else 1 end
```

returns 1